# Grep exact match not working

Tags: bash, shell

I've a properties file

```
myprop2=this is with <br/>
```

When I'm trying to grep for `<br>`

```
grep "^myprop.*=.`*<br>*`" MyProject.properties | xargs | cut -d '=' -f 1
```

Why is it finding **myprop2** ?

Note : I'm finding `<br>` instead of `<br/>` ( without the ending tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` after the right angular bracket makes it 0 or more times so safely ignored in the match.  I think what you meant is `...>.*`

Also, using look-ahead you can eliminate some pipes

```
grep -oP "myprop.(?==.*<br>.*)" file
```

will give the same without xargs and cut

Comment: The `grep` solution is helpful, but you should mention that it requires _GNU_ `grep`. While the `>*` explanation is correct in principle, the OP's more immediate problem is the enclosing of `*<br>*` in _backticks_.
Also, while `>.*` instead of `>*` does work, it's worth pointing out that just `>` will do, given that the remainder of the line needn't be matched.

Answer (score 1):

Your double-quoted string contains *backticks* around `*<br>*` (an instance of [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution)), which means that Bash will attempt to *execute* `*<br>*` as a *command* - which will fail for a variety of reasons - and expand the expression to the stdout output produced by that command.

Since that failed command produces no *stdout* output, the `` `...` `` expression expands to the null (empty) string, which means that `grep` will see the following string literal:
`^myprop.*=."`

Any line that starts with `myprop`, eventually followed by a `=` and at least 1 char. matches this regular expression, irrespective of what follows - which is why the `myprop2` line matched.

If the backticks were meant to be matched as *literals*, you could either have escaped them as `` \` `` or used a *single*-quoted string instead.
(In case you think that `*` chars. must be escaped in quoted strings in order to be treated literally: they don't - only *unquoted* use requires escaping).

However, [karakfa's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36243148/45375) correctly implies that even if you didn't enclose `*<br>*` in backticks, following `>` with duplication symbol `*` means that *any* number of instances of `>` - including none - matches.

Since `grep` matches substrings of lines by default, this effectively matches *any* remainder of the line, including one starting with `/>`, which therefore matches `<br/>` too.

Therefore, while following `>` with `.*` instead of `*` does solve that problem, it is not necessary - ending the regular expression with `>` will do.

His *GNU* `grep` solution (because only GNU `grep` supports the `-P` option to enable support for [PCREs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) to enable such features as look-ahead assertions) can therefore be simplified to:

```
grep -oP 'myprop.*(?==.*<br>)' MyProject.properties
```

<sup>Note the use of *single* quotes, which is the better choice for strings that need not be interpolated, to guarantee their use as-is.</sup>

If using GNU `grep` is not an option, use (note that there's no reason to use `xargs`):

```
grep '^myprop.*=.*<br>' MyProject.properties | cut -d '=' -f 1
```

Alternatively, use `awk`:

```
awk -F= '$1 ~ /^myprop/ && $2 ~ /<br>/ { print $1 }' MyProject.properties
```

Or, if it's only about matching the *value*, irrespective of the property *name*:

```
awk -F= '$2 ~ /<br>/ { print $1 }' MyProject.properties
```

Comment: I simply love your answer ...and appreciate the amount of effort you have put in to elaborate. Hats off !

Comment: @NoviceUser: I appreciate the nice feedback; I'm glad you found the answer useful.